# pass a single row from 2d vector to function

Tags: c++, vector

With the help of SO members, the following program successfully converts a static 1D array into a 2D vector by considering below criteria:

Each time an element with value = 0 is encountered, a new row is created. Basically when a 0 is encountered, row value is increased and column value is reset to 0. If a non-zero value is encountered, the row value is maintained and column value is increased.

```
// declarations
int givenArray[9] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 2, 1};
std::vector<int>::size_type j;
std::vector<int>::size_type i;

vector<vector<int>> my2dArray;
vector<int> dArray;

void calc(vector<int>&, int);
int task;
int sum = 0;

int main() {    
    for (int i = 0; i < 9;
         i++) // iterate through all elements of the given array
    {
        if (i == 0) // adding the first element
        {
            my2dArray.resize(my2dArray.size() + 1);
            my2dArray.back().push_back(givenArray[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if (givenArray[i] == 0) // re-size if 0 is encountered
        {
            my2dArray.resize(my2dArray.size() + 1);
        }
        my2dArray.back().push_back(givenArray[i]);
    }

    for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; i < my2dArray.size();
         i++) {
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < my2dArray[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << my2dArray[i][j] << ' ';

            if (my2dArray[i].size() > 2) {
                task = my2dArray[i].size();
                calc(my2dArray[i], task);
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void calc(vector<int>& dArray, int task) {
    int max = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < task; j++) {
        if (dArray[i] > max)
            dArray[i] = max;
    }
    cout << "\nMax is" << max;
}
```

**However, I want to pass a single row of 2D vector 2dArray to function calc if the number of columns for each row exceeds 2.** Function calc aims to find maximum value of all the elements in the passed row. The above program doesn't yield the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, you're unclear about your conditions. Should a new row be started encountering `0` or if the number of columns exceeds `2`?

Comment: What is the desire behavior, only call the `calc` function when all the rows has `size > 2` or called only with the rows with `size > 2`.

Comment: i want to call calc function and pass each row which has size > 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvements:

- `i and j` global variables are not needed, you are declaring the variables of the loops in the loop initialization (ex: for (**int i = 0**; i < 9; i++), the same for the other loops).
- It's better not to used global variables, only when strictly necessary (with careful analysis of why). In this case it's not necessary.
- The `typedef` are for more easy access to inner `typedef` of the type (ex: `size_type`).
- You were doing the call to `calc` method in every iteration of the inner loop, and iterating over the same row multiple times, this call should be executed once per row.
- Using the size of array `givenArray` as constant in the code is not recommended, later you could add some elements to the array and forgot to update that constant, it's better to declare a variable and calculated generally (with sizeof).
- There is no need to pass the size of the vector to method `calc` if you are passing the vector.
- As recommended earlier it's better to use `std::max_element` of `algorithm` header.

If you could use C++11 the `givenArray` could be converted to an `std::vector<int>` and maintain the easy initialization.

Code (Tested in GCC 4.9.0)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<int> list_t;
typedef std::vector<list_t> list2d_t;

void calc(list_t& dArray, long& actual_max) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dArray.size(); j++) {
        if (dArray[j] > actual_max) {
            actual_max = dArray[j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Max is " << actual_max << "\n";
}

void calc(list_t& dArray) {
    long actual_max = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dArray.size(); j++) {
        if (dArray[j] > actual_max) {
            actual_max = dArray[j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Max is " << actual_max << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int givenArray[9] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 2, 1};
    int givenArraySize = sizeof(givenArray) / sizeof(givenArray[0]);

    list2d_t my2dArray(1);
    list_t dArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < givenArraySize; i++) {
        if (givenArray[i] == 0) {
            my2dArray.push_back(list_t());
        } else {
            my2dArray.back().push_back(givenArray[i]);
        }
    }

    long max = 0;
    for (list2d_t::size_type i = 0; i < my2dArray.size(); i++) {
        for (list_t::size_type j = 0; j < my2dArray[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << my2dArray[i][j] << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
        if (my2dArray[i].size() > 2) {
            // if you need the max of all the elements in rows with size > 2 uncoment bellow and comment other call
            // calc(my2dArray[i], max); 

            calc(my2dArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Obtained Output:

```
1 2 3 
Max is 3
4 
1 2 1 
Max is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

1. You don't need to loop over `j` in the main function - your `calc` function already does this.
2. Your `calc` function loops over `j`, but uses the global variable `i` when accessing the array.
3. Your `calc` function assigns the current `max` value to the array, rather than assigning the array value to `max`

Answer (score 0):

*Function calc aims to find maximum value of all the elements in the passed row. The above program doesn't yield the desired output.*

Instead of writing a function, you could have used `std::max_element`.

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int maxVal = *std::max_element(my2dArray[i].begin(), my2dArray[i].begin() + task);
cout << "\Max is " << maxVal;
```